# How can I slove this Axios Interceptor problem?

Tags: reactjs, post, react-redux, axios, interceptor

I am new with Axios interceptor and I could not figure out what is wrong with this code.Is this the right way to pass the data(body) using Axios Interceptor to make a post request?

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const userService = {
    login
};

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://**********/api/v1'
})

const loginRequestHandler = (request) => {
 request.data['email','password']={email,password} 
  return request
}

axios.interceptors.request.use(
  request => loginRequestHandler(request),
  error =>  Promise.reject(error)
);

 function login(handlerEnabled){
    axiosInstance.post('/auth/local',{handlerEnabled})
}
```

Comment: axios interceptor are generally used for handling global error handling, or adding a token to every request header. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Hi, I want to know the way to send the data(body) during the post API request.